# Parse error in Alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-2, alamofire

I am getting this response.

```
SUCCESS: {
    msg = "Login successfully";
    "type_id" = 1;
    "user_id" = 2;
}
```

I used this code.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http:/www.abc.com" , parameters: ["consumer_key": "Og5pRGI2V"]).responseJSON { response in

                    print(response)
                   let employees = response["employees"]! as NSDictionary //getting error type response has no subscript member
                }
```

Which is type of response ? How to parse this "msg","user_id" ?. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire parses the response data and stores it in the response object.  You can get it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http:/www.abc.com" , parameters: ["consumer_key": "Og5pRGI2V"]).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
    if let dict = response.result.value {
        let msg = dict["msg"]
        let userId = dict["user_id"]
        // Do things with the values
    }
}
```